# Meaning of 蓋聞, just after the end of the opening poem in Journey to the West

Tags: translation

I'm attempting a retranslation of Journey to the West that adheres more closely to the Chinese than translations I've found so far.

In the Jenner translation, this is left out.

In Anthony Yu's translation, it's translated as "We heard that", but this doesn't explain to me what the 蓋 means.

I'm guessing that the sense of the phrase is something like "Low key the news is", or "On the down low, hear that...".

The original text is here:
https://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/23962/pg23962.html

Comment: 盖's pronouciation in ancient chinese is actually the sound that you open your mouth and start speaking, so very natural, as you say “well...” in english

Comment: Does it have any relation to the notion of a top or a lid in this context? Like "from the top" or it being the "lid" of the proceeding text?

Comment: `@Step Start` it has this functionality but not here. See the comments below by `@r13`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

“蓋” is a starting particle, void meaning ([發語詞，提起下文，無義](https://dict.revised.moe.edu.tw/dictView.jsp?ID=3992&q=1&word=%E8%93%8B#order1))

> 蓋聞天地之數

maybe, “[everyone] known that, the fate of universe”, . . .

have fun :)

Comment: Correct. 文言虛詞（①發語詞，如“～聞”；②表大概如此，如“～近之矣”；③連詞，表示原因，如“有所不知，～未學也”）